# Cakephp run time bindmodel associaton group by is not working

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

with the updated code i am trying to bind relation between payment and website , but it seems group by is not working. and i am getting lot of duplicate result.

**Updated :**

```
$this->Website->unBindModel(array('hasMany' => array('User')));
$this->Website->bindModel(array(
                                'hasMany' => array(
                                    'Payment' => array(
                                        'className' => 'Payment',
                                        'foreignKey' => 'website_id',
                                        'fields' => array(
                                            'Payment.id',
                                            'Payment.website_id',
                                            'Payment.created',
                                            'Payment.user_id',
                                            'Payment.is_get_invoice'
                                        ) ,
                                        'conditions' => array(
                                            'Payment.website_id <>' => '0',
                                            'Payment.is_get_invoice' => '0'
                                        ),
                                        'order' => array(
                                            'Payment.id DESC'
                                        ),
                                        'group' => array(
                                            'Payment.website_id' //Its not working
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        );


$this->Website->recursive = 1;
$webPayments = $this->Website->find('all', array('fields' => array('Website.id'),'contain' => array('Payment')));
```

**Old :**

I am trying to bind and unbind model runtime.
but its giving me error. even association is not working.

```
$this->Website->unBindModel(array(
    'hasMany' => array(
        'User'
    )
));
$this->Website->bindModel(array(
    'hasMany' => array(
        'Payment' => array(
            'className' => 'Payment',
            'foreignKey' => 'website_id'
        )
    )
));
$this->Website->recursive = 1;
$webPayments = $this->Website->find('all', array(
    'fields' => array(
        'Website.id',
        'Payment.id',
        'Payment.website_id',
        'Payment.created',
        'Payment.user_id'
    ) ,
    'conditions' => array(
        'Payment.website_id <>' => '0',
        'Payment.is_get_invoice' => '0'
    ) ,
    'order' => array(
        'Payment.id DESC',
        'group' => array(
            'Payment.website_id'
        )
    )
));

pr($webPayments);
```

**Error:**

Columnnotfound: 1054 Unknowncolumn 'Payment.id' in 'field list'

```
SELECT`Website` . `id`, `Payment` . `id`, `Payment` . `website_id`, `Payment` . `created`, `Payment` . `user_id`, FROM`websites` AS `Website`WHERE`Payment` . `website_id` <> 0 AND `Payment` . `is_get_invoice` = '0' AND `Payment` . `created` > '2017-04-13 07:07:54' GROUPBY `Payment` . `website_id` ORDERBY `Payment` . `id` DESC
```

Comment: Which version of cake are you using?

Comment: @GeorgeM Cakephp 2.6

Comment: You did well in the update to put 'order' and 'group' on the same level.

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve a list of all the Websites and the **last** associated Payment?

Comment: yes @InigoFlores but with custom bindmodel

Answer (score 2):

Try using contain like this:

```
$webPayments = $this->Website->find('all', array(
    'fields' => array(
        'Website.id',       
    ),
    'contain' => array(
        'Payment' => array(
            'fields' => array(
                'Payment.id',
                'Payment.website_id',
                'Payment.created',
                'Payment.user_id'
            ),
            'conditions' => array(
                'Payment.website_id <>' => '0',
                'Payment.is_get_invoice' => '0'
            ),
            'order' => array(
                'Payment.id DESC',
                'group' => array(
                    'Payment.website_id'
                )
            )
        )
    )
));
```

https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html

Answer (score 1):

Are your models declared properly for the association?  You should have

```
class Payment extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Payment';
    public $actAs = array('Containable');

public $belongsTo = array (
    'Website' => array(
        'className' => 'Website',
        'foreignKey' => 'website_id'
    )
)
[...]
}

class Website extends AppModel {
    var $name 'Website';
    public $actAs = array('Containable');

    public $hasMany = array(
        'Payment' => array(
             'className'=>'Payment',
             'order' => 'Payment.id DESC'
         )
    )
[...]
}
```

I find that declaring things as low as possible in the model really works better than trying to do it on the fly with a query.. If the association is properly declared in the model itself you shouldn't have to dork with binding/unbinding like that..

Comment: Try setting 'recursive' to 2 also.  I know you only need 1, but 1 is a special value, if you set it to the unnecessary 2 you have a better chance to get the data you need correctly.  In my experience :-)

Comment: Uh oh..  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10746506/cakephp-wont-apply-group-by-condition  no hint of version, but it's disquieting. Note that modifying the core directly is asking for trouble, you'd have to make your own copy and modify that.

Comment: Thankyou,. but i am looking for solution which works with bind and unbind.. If i will change in payment model and website model , then it could effect on other side, and there query could be heave as latest association also will work , thats why i choose bind and unbind

Answer (score 0):

The `hasMany` association does not support the `group by` key.

In this particular case, what you are trying to achieve by the incorrect use of `group` is to return just one result. Note that the same functionality can be accomplished by using the `limit` key, which is supported.

The code would be the following:

```
$this->Website->unBindModel(array('hasMany' => array('User')));
$this->Website->bindModel(array(
                            'hasMany' => array(
                                'Payment' => array(
                                    'className' => 'Payment',
                                    'foreignKey' => 'website_id',
                                    'fields' => array(
                                        'Payment.id',
                                        'Payment.website_id',
                                        'Payment.created',
                                        'Payment.user_id',
                                        'Payment.is_get_invoice'
                                    ) ,
                                    'conditions' => array(
                                        'Payment.website_id <>' => '0',
                                        'Payment.is_get_invoice' => '0'
                                    ),
                                    'order' => array(
                                        'Payment.id DESC'
                                    ),
                                    'limit' => 1
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    );
```

Reference

- [CakePHP 2.x hasMany Association](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany)